# jmx pass string array

Tags: java, jmx

Is it possible to pass an array of string to a method exposed by the MBean. If I have a method with an array parameter, JConsole disables the button to invoke the method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use Jolokia (http://www.jolokia.org) (an agent based approach for JMX remoting as alternative to JSR-160 connectors), you could use j4psh, which comes as part of jmx4perl (http://www.jmx4perl.org). This is a readline based, consext sensitive command line shell with syntax highlighting. Simple array types (string, boolean, int, ..) can be given as a single comma separated list argument from within the shell for operation and attributes to set.

Answer (score 3):

The JMX spec permits it, yes, but it's up to the JMX tool in question to then support the ability to handle them.

JConsole, apparently, does not. This is pretty common amongst simple visual JMX tools like this. JBoss's JMX console has a similar limitation.

Remember, JMX's uses go way beyond tools like these, which are really little more than toys.

Comment: Other than using JConsole i do not know how to achieve this. Can you let me know some tools or other methods using which I can pass arrays.

Comment: @user373201: Off the top of my head, no

Comment: Is it possible to do this with MXBean

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to pass a string array is to send a CSV and split the string within the JMX method.